# Is JBoss a prerequisite to build a JMS queue?

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I need to create a JMSQueue but I can't use JBoss. I'm new to this and I need somebody's advice as to whether I can build a JMSQueue with my own server or using any other alternative.
Can you also please send me links to examples that use other alternatives? 
I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: JBoss is just one application server. There are plenty other options. `JMSQueue` defines just an interface - the way you implement it, is up to you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I have my own server that I'm intending to use but I don't know how.

Comment: Basically you wouldn't need a server to implement `JMSQueue`. But if other applications want to use your implementation, the most common approach is to use an application server. Besides JBoss, there is, e.g., Tomcat (free) or Websphere (commercial). As for `JMSQueue` itself - it is just an interface. Implement all the methods the intreface requires and you're fine. An interface description can, eg., be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/msg/client/jms/JmsQueue.html).

Comment: You might have a look at http://activemq.apache.org/ or https://mq.java.net/